# How do I submit a TestFlight build as a team member

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, iphone-developer-program

I want to deploy a build on **TestFlight** as a team member. But there is a problem. My organization added me as a developer to **App Store Connect** but my development team doesn't show up in `Xcode` so that I can sign the app using their certificate. So what exactly my organization should do to allow me to deploy builds to **TestFlight** using their account? I'm just stuck in all of that *Apple Developer portal* menus.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you want to submit the app from xcode?

Comment: @Lion yes, this is the plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your organization has given access to you from the `appstoreconnect(iTunesConnect)` then it is not possible. Your organization must give you access from `developer portal (i.e. developer.apple.com)`. Now, if your organization registered as individual in developer portal then they do not have option to give access to someone but they registered as a organization then they can give you access from developer portal and in xcode you can add your apple id and select automatically code signin and you will find your organization in the drop-down of the team list in general tab.

Second thing you can manually code signin by getting provisioning profile and valid certificate(.p12).